# Display rows with one or more NaN values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe in which some rows contain missing values.

```
In [31]: df.head()
Out[31]: 
                             alpha1  alpha2    gamma1    gamma2       chi2min  
filename                                                                        
M66_MI_NSRh35d32kpoints.dat  0.8016  0.9283  1.000000  0.074804  3.985599e+01   
F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat          0.0000  0.0000       NaN  0.000000  1.000000e+25   
F62_sMI_St22d7.dat           1.7210  3.8330  0.237480  0.150000  1.091832e+01   
F41_Car_HOC498d.dat          1.1670  2.8090  0.364190  0.300000  7.966335e+00   
F78_MI_547d.dat              1.8970  5.4590  0.095319  0.100000  2.593468e+01
```

I want to display those rows on the screen. If I try `df.isnull()`, it gives a long dataframe with `True` and `False`. Is there any way by which I can select these rows and print them on the screen?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with parameter `axis=1` for check at least one `True` in row by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
d = {'filename': ['M66_MI_NSRh35d32kpoints.dat', 'F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat', 'F62_sMI_St22d7.dat', 'F41_Car_HOC498d.dat', 'F78_MI_547d.dat'], 'alpha1': [0.8016, 0.0, 1.721, 1.167, 1.897], 'alpha2': [0.9283, 0.0, 3.833, 2.809, 5.459], 'gamma1': [1.0, np.nan, 0.23748000000000002, 0.36419, 0.095319], 'gamma2': [0.074804, 0.0, 0.15, 0.3, np.nan], 'chi2min': [39.855990000000006, 1e+25, 10.91832, 7.966335000000001, 25.93468]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('filename')
```

---

```
print (df)
                             alpha1  alpha2    gamma1    gamma2       chi2min
filename                                                                     
M66_MI_NSRh35d32kpoints.dat  0.8016  0.9283  1.000000  0.074804  3.985599e+01
F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat          0.0000  0.0000       NaN  0.000000  1.000000e+25
F62_sMI_St22d7.dat           1.7210  3.8330  0.237480  0.150000  1.091832e+01
F41_Car_HOC498d.dat          1.1670  2.8090  0.364190  0.300000  7.966335e+00
F78_MI_547d.dat              1.8970  5.4590  0.095319       NaN  2.593468e+01
```

**Explanation**:

```
print (df.isna())
                            alpha1 alpha2 gamma1 gamma2 chi2min
filename                                                       
M66_MI_NSRh35d32kpoints.dat  False  False  False  False   False
F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat          False  False   True  False   False
F62_sMI_St22d7.dat           False  False  False  False   False
F41_Car_HOC498d.dat          False  False  False  False   False
F78_MI_547d.dat              False  False  False   True   False

print (df.isna().any(axis=1))
filename
M66_MI_NSRh35d32kpoints.dat    False
F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat             True
F62_sMI_St22d7.dat             False
F41_Car_HOC498d.dat            False
F78_MI_547d.dat                 True
dtype: bool

df1 = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
                     alpha1  alpha2    gamma1  gamma2       chi2min
filename                                                           
F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat   0.000   0.000       NaN     0.0  1.000000e+25
F78_MI_547d.dat       1.897   5.459  0.095319     NaN  2.593468e+01
```

Comment: axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, or tuple/list thereof
Pass tuple or list to drop on multiple axes

Comment: Suppose you want to apply `isnull()` to some columns only?

Comment: df[df['gamma1','gamma2'].isna().any(axis=1)] or for one column it is  df[df['gamma1'].isna()]. The idea is same regardless of whether we check for null values in entire dataframe or few columns. we get boolean series after applying isna() which is used for boolean indexing.

Comment: An important note: if you are trying to _just_ access rows with NaN values (and do _not_ want to access rows which contain nulls but not NaNs), this doesn't work - `isna()` will retrieve both.  This is especially applicable when your dataframe is composed of numbers alongside other object types, such as strings.

Answer (score 20):

Use `df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]` for python 3.6 or above.

Answer (score 6):

`df.isna().any()` returns the columns status for nan values. Hence, a better way to observe and analyze the nan values would be:

`df.loc[:, df.isna().any()]`

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eaLx.png)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose gamma1 and gamma2 are two such columns for which **df.isnull().any()** gives **True** value , the following code can be used to print the rows.

```
bool1 = pd.isnull(df['gamma1'])
bool2 = pd.isnull(df['gamma2'])
df[bool1]
df[bool2]
```

Comment: I also like `pd.isna(df['gamma1'])` 

Answer (score 3):

Can try this too, almost similar previous answers.

```
    d = {'filename': ['M66_MI_NSRh35d32kpoints.dat', 'F71_sMI_DMRI51d.dat', 'F62_sMI_St22d7.dat', 'F41_Car_HOC498d.dat', 'F78_MI_547d.dat'], 'alpha1': [0.8016, 0.0, 1.721, 1.167, 1.897], 'alpha2': [0.9283, 0.0, 3.833, 2.809, 5.459], 'gamma1': [1.0, np.nan, 0.23748000000000002, 0.36419, 0.095319], 'gamma2': [0.074804, 0.0, 0.15, 0.3, np.nan], 'chi2min': [39.855990000000006, 1e+25, 10.91832, 7.966335000000001, 25.93468]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('filename')
```

[image]

Count of null values in each column.

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

[image]

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the display is already viewed above, next step could be drop the nan records, you could follow the below snippet.

```
df = df.dropna()
```