# Set a pandas column Boolean value based on other columns in the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume a DataFrame

```
    C1      C2      C3
1   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   20.1    15      200
3   NaN     12      100
4   22.5    8       80
```

I want to create a new column based on a summarizing boolean of the rest of the row. For example, are any of the values NaN? In that case, my new column value would be "False" for that row.

Or, perhaps, are ALL of the values NaN? In that case, I might want the new column to say False but otherwise True (we do have some values)

I considered using `df.notnan()` to create a Boolean DataFrame,

```
    C1      C2      C3
1   False   False   False
2   True    True    True
3   False   True    True
4   True    True    True
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I could not come up with a way to create the fourth column based on OR-ing the existing items in each row.

Also, a generic solution would be nice, one that doesn't require building an interim DF of Booleans.

Background: I have a dataset. Nutrient values are only sampled occasionally, so many of the rows do not contain those values. I would like to have a "Nutrients Sampled" column where the value is True or False based on whether I can expect to see any nutrient sample data in this record. There are 6 possible nutrients and I don't want to check all 6 columns.

I can write the code that checks all 6 columns; I just can't seem to create a new column with a truth value.

Comment: This may help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424199/display-rows-with-one-or-more-nan-values-in-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424199/display-rows-with-one-or-more-nan-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `any` and `all` methods which are available on the data frame, just have to pass the argument `axis=1` to operate along

example:

```
df['C4'] = pd.notnull(df).any(axis=1)

     C1    C2     C3     C4
0   NaN   NaN    NaN  False
1  20.1  15.0  200.0   True
2   NaN  12.0  100.0   True
3  22.5   8.0   80.0   True
```

Comment: But how would I do this if I only care about C2 and C3?

Comment: you can make a list of columns you care about, e.g. `mycols=['C2', 'C3']`, and then subset apply the statement on that subset `df['C4'] = pd.notnull(df[mycols]).any(1)`

Answer (score 2):

I feel like we should using `all`

```
df['New']=~df.isna().all(1)
df
     C1    C2     C3    New
1   NaN   NaN    NaN  False
2  20.1  15.0  200.0   True
3   NaN  12.0  100.0   True
4  22.5   8.0   80.0   True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` method and define a function to map rows to a boolean.

Here is a function, you can customize based on your need (e.g. you can use `all` instead of `any`):

```
# if at least one of the values is NaN
def my_function(row):
    return any(row[['C1', 'C2', 'C3']].isna())
```

And here is how to apply it to your dataframe and add new column:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(my_function, axis=1)

    C1      C2      C3      new_column
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     True
1   20.1    15.0    200.0   False
2   NaN     12.0    100.0   True
3   22.5    8.0     80.0    False
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
# interim df
df = {"C1": [False, True, False, True], ...
df ["C4"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.C1 or x.C2 or X.C3, axis=1)
```

Or ... directly as

```
original_df["C4"] = original_df.apply(lambda x: np.any(np.isnan(x)), axis = 1)
```

Regards,