# Is there a why to create a binary column that indicates records with missing values

Tags: python

it's my first time using stackoverflow to ask a question so pls let me know if i'm doing anything wrong (in terms of asking)
my data looks like this now - as attached - I'm wondering if there's any way to create a binary column that indicates records with missing values as my goal is to obtain the proportion of records with missing values for each country.
thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yctk1.png)

Comment: Could you provide what you have tried?

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're doing, what technologies you're using, etc.  But basically sounds like you just need to read up on how to make a data model, using whatever database solution you're using.

Comment: thanks guys, i'll try to think about it first then see how to ask better

Answer (score 0):

This question was partially answered here: [How to select rows with one or more nulls from a pandas DataFrame without listing columns explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247586/how-to-select-rows-with-one-or-more-nulls-from-a-pandas-dataframe-without-listin)
For this case the answer is:

```
wv['row_has_nan'] = wv.isnull().any(axis=1)
```